# datatypes that act as global need no header files. How to find #define for OS and Linux version. Is there any header file that get included by default

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, constants, global

If I make a C program or C++ program so on Linux datatypes need no header files to be included (at least true for `int`, `char`, and `void`). so I believe they are common in different Operating Systems including Linux, windows, android.

I like to know if I am make a program or kernel module is there any Global-to-entire-OS #define in C that I can use to find what Operating system and version of it is running. ANd where exactly a header file where I can find these details in Linux or a web page on the internet. So they must be in My debian system some where I dont know

I like to make a device driver. So some header files will be targeting specific architecture. But if Operating system is different then I will not try to include the header files in c source files at the top.

So if these details something like global `#define OS_Name` exists in my system header files that need no inclusion of any header files then that will help me a lot. I need the names of those #define names and where I can find them all listed on my system or on any webpage on internet. I am using linux -- But I dont think it matters

Example what I would Like to have

```
     #Ifdef OS_IS_LINUX
      #include <asm-generic/ioports.h>
     #endif
```

Comment: Provide some [mre] in your question. Study the source code of the [Linux kernel](https://kernel.org/). I don't think that you could easily write a driver which works on both Linux & Windows. Read of course [Operating systems: three easy pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Consider using [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/). Ask also on https://kernelnewbies.org/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have added ro my question with example what I like to do

Comment: was `uname()` too difficult to give the correct answer. Wodks on Linux/Windows/Android/Iphone from sys/utsname.h

Comment: Your questions is unclear, probably because you have provided too much irrelevant info. Are you just looking for ways to detect OS in your source code, like `#ifdef __linux__`?

Comment: The types `int` and `char` and the non-type `void` are intrinsic types in the C language and not platform-specific, though some of their characteristics are platform-specific.  Those types are not defined in any header on any platform.  There is no way to define them.  They are keywords too.

Answer (score 1):

```
   echo | gcc -E -dM -
```

No header files needed